# Jquery Drag and Drop from several lists to another (sortable) one

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to create a Jquery-based **Playlist Assembler**.
The playlist will be created by dragging and dropping items into it from several lists - each list for a different category.

These are the thing I would like to achieve:

- Every item in the categories lists will have a button which will add it to the end of the playlist, and remove it from its original list.
- Every item in the new playlist will have a button which removes it from the playlist and places it back in its original place in its original list, however if items from the original list were moved as well, the removed item will be placed **according to the changes that were made** - (see image below) if item 2 in Category 3 as added to the playlist, and then Item 3 from Category 3 (that is now being dragged in the image) was removed from the playlist - Item 3 would be placed between Item 1 and Item 4 in Category 3.

  Items will be able contain data (item's duration, item's src, etc..).

  Items in the playlist will be sortable.

  Items that **are not** in the playlist will **not** be sortable.

  Drop placeholders - When dragging an item to the playlist, other items in it will make room for the that item by shifting to allow white space between them. (Like [here](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder))

[Here is what I have in mind (Pretty much...)](http://postimg.org/image/5jsld0r21/)

I've found many Drag and Drop Jquery plugins on the web, yet none of them enabled me to combine all the functions I would like to achieve.
I have literally no idea where to start from, so I would really appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explore some HTML5 canvas libraries, like KineticJS, EaselJS... and then choose the one for your project. Using a library would save a lot of your time.